# Filter responseText with javascript tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, prototype

I am getting a responseText from `Prototype` which contains lots of JavaScript tags.

If I use `console.log(responseText)` it displays the JavaScript tag. Further more i process the responseText to get particular class content.

For example:

```
var result = jQuery(".category-products",jQuery(response.responseText)).html();
```

Then I use `jQuery('.category-products').html(result);`

But by doing this I am not getting JavaScript. Which I want to evaluate further. Please help.

Sorry for weak English.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery('.category-products').text(result);

Comment: Yes, i have tried but it simply put the simple text.

Comment: When i filter the responseText and alert it. it doesn't give me any Javascript Tags.

Comment: I got the javascript like this : 
var jScript = jQuery('.category-products script',response.responsText).text();

Now problem in eval...

Comment: Finally Problem solved

jQuery(response.responseText).filter(".responseid").each(function(i){
     jScript+=jQuery(this).html();

});

Comment: @YagneshPonkiya Post your answer as an answer, then accept it as THE answer so others can see your question has been answered. Thanks.